# How to use soft order with JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I want to use table JOIN with soft order for these tables:

```
 CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 USER_NAME TEXT NOT NULL,
 PASSWD TEXT,
 FIRST_NAME TEXT,
 LAST_NAME TEXT,
 E_MAIL TEXT NOT NULL,
 COUNTRY TEXT,
 STATE TEXT,
 CITY TEXT,
 ADDRESS TEXT,
 STATUS INTEGER,
 SECURITY_QUESTION TEXT,
 SECURITY_ANSWER TEXT,
 LAST_PASSWD_RESET DATE,
 DESCRIPTION TEXT,
 LAST_UPDATED DATE,
 CREATED DATE
)
;

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE ACCOUNT

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT ADD CONSTRAINT KEY1 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
;

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT ADD CONSTRAINT USER_NAME UNIQUE (USER_NAME)
;

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT ADD CONSTRAINT E_MAIL UNIQUE (E_MAIL)
;

-- TABLE ACCOUNT_ROLE

CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT_ROLE(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 USER_NAME TEXT NOT NULL,
 ROLE INTEGER,
 PERMISSION TEXT,
 LAST_UPDATED DATE,
 CREATED DATE
)
;

-- CREATE INDEXES FOR TABLE ACCOUNT_ROLE

CREATE INDEX IX_RELATIONSHIP19 ON ACCOUNT_ROLE (ID)
;

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE ACCOUNT_ROLE

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT_ROLE ADD CONSTRAINT KEY26 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
;

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT_ROLE ADD CONSTRAINT RELATIONSHIP19 FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES ACCOUNT (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
;
```

Working query:

```
SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT ORDER BY %S %S offset ? limit ?
```

I tried this SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM ACCOUNT_ROLE
    INNER JOIN ACCOUNT ON ACCOUNT.ID = ACCOUNT_ROLE.ID
ORDER BY Account.%S Account.%S offset ? limit ?
```

But I get this error message:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "Account"
  Position: 99
```

How I can fix this query? I would like to get the data from two tables and sort it based in value.

Comment: You need a comma between the columns in the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: I get Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column account.asc does not exist
  Position: 100

Comment: How are you running the query? It looks like you're using Format or something like that (`%S`), in combination with perl database parameters (`?`). In that case, you must be passing "_asc_" as the first parameter to your Format function.

Comment: Put a space before %s instead of a dot.

Comment: @jarlh I tried this `SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_ROLE INNER JOIN ACCOUNT ON ACCOUNT.ID = ACCOUNT_ROLE.ID ORDER BY ACCOUNT %S ACCOUNT %S offset ? limit ?` But I get `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "ID"`

Comment: Remove stuff until it works. Skip the LIMIT and OFFSET. Skip the ORDER BY etc.

Comment: The basic query is working `SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_ROLE INNER JOIN ACCOUNT ON ACCOUNT.ID = ACCOUNT_ROLE.ID`

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you are asking so instead I am proposing a few troubleshooting steps:

1. It looks like you are trying to do some query preprocessing.  Please log the query after this is done and troubleshoot based on that.  Failing that, check the PostgreSQL logs for the failing query text string (the logged query is better because of how placeholders are handled).
2. Once you are looking at the query itself, then look at it for syntax errors.

The problems are almost certainly in portions of your code you have not shown us.  Knowing how to get the troubleshooting process started however can be worth mentioning.